# How to count all the rows in a fixed range containing a specific word in one of the cells and the sum of other two cells being greater than a const?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've made an Excel sheet to ease some calculations, but I'm stuck to the point explained in the title. The data is a list of rows containing a date, two names, and two numbers, like the following one:

[image]

and so on.

I do need a formulae capable to count all the rows containing for example "Jane" where amount1+amount2 > 4.

So far I've made some test with COUNTIFS(...): this is a working example of a formula which counts all the rows containing the word "Jane" in both NameA and NameB fields where amount1 > 0 and amount2 > 0:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A100,"Jane",D2:D100,&">0",E2:E100,&">0"),COUNTIFS(B1:B100,"Jane",D2:D100,&">0",E2:E100,&">0"))
```

Same approach doesn't seem to work trying to search for the sum of the two amount fields, as follows:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A100,"Jane",D2:D100,"+"&E2:E100"&>4"),COUNTIFS(B1:B100,"Jane",D2:D100,"+"&E2:E100"&>4"))
```

Comment: Sorry, i've mismatched column names. Please consider A1.A100 as B1:B100 and B1:B100 as C1:C100. And rows starts from 1 not 0, of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNTIFS does not work with addition like that.  One will need to switch to SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A1:A100="Jane")+(B1:B100="Jane")>0)*(D2:D100+E2:E100>4))
```

Comment: thank you, it works. Being a similar question, may i ask you how would you do to get the same results just fro column NameA or column NameB, or i need to ask another question?

Comment: change `((A1:A100="Jane")+(B1:B100="Jane")>0)*` to just one or the other like `(A1:A100="Jane")*`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now a lot of hand made work gets reduced to a simple drag'n'drop thing.